# Add Javascript code to functions.php childtheme

Tags: functions, child-theme

I would like to add the following JavaScript function to a wordpress child theme (functions.php). Unfortunately I am not able to make it.
Function:

```
$.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate = function (s) {

       s = String(s);

       return s;

   };
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'listingpr-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
    
    echo "<script>fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate();</script>";
   
 
    ?>
```

But it dont work. Please help me to fix my issue.
Thanks you!

regards
shotput_wp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action("wp_footer","custom_footer_script");
function custom_footer_script(){
?>
    <script>
          //your script here
    </script>  
<?php

}
```

This will add script to footer

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the code just by echoing like that. The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action doesn't work that way.

So you have two options.

First option, make a new file called `cityautocomplete.js` and put it in your child theme directory/folder.  In that file paste the following:

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate = function(s) {
            s = String(s);
            return s;
        };
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

Then, in your `functions.php` where you attempted to paste the script, add the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'cityautocomplete', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'cityautocomplete.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.x', true );
```

*(Change the 1.x to match your child theme version number.)*

That's the preferred method.  You could/should even consider naming the file something like `child.js` and then putting any additional javascript/jQuery in there so you're only enqueueing one file rather than a myriad of files with simple bits of JS.

The second option would be to print out the script contents in the theme head or footer.  Paste the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
    function cityAutocomplete(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate = function(s) {
                s = String(s);
                return s;
            };
        } );
    } )( jQuery );
    </script>
<?php
    };
```

Then depending on if you need it in the `<head>` tag or if it works better in the footer, use one of these:

`add_action( 'wp_head', 'cityAutocomplete' ); //for <head> inclusion`

`add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cityAutocomplete' ); //for footer inclusion`

Don't use both or you'll double up your script.